# spring jpa join and query repository

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have `User` class like this:

```
{
     ...
     Long userID;
     ...     
     List<UserMovieRole> userMovieRoles=...
}
```

A Movie class like this:

```
{
    ...
    Long movieID; 
    ...     
    List<UserMovieRole> userMovieRoles=...
}
```

I have another class UserMovieRole like this:

```
{
    Long userMovieRoleID;
    Role role;
    ...
    User user;
    ...
    Movie movie;
}
```

Now I want to query on `UserMovieRole` and select where userID and movieID is given.

In sql I can simply write, I can simply write a join and where sql to select.

But in spring boot jpa query, it seems I can't do that, how can I do that?

Here is what I have tried:

- `@Query("select umr from UserMovieRole umr where umr.user.userID=?1 and umr.movie.movieID=?2")`
- `@Query("select umrj from UserMovieRole.user full join UserMovieRole.movie umrj where umrj.userID=?1 and umrj.movieID=?2")`

I dont't know if any of these are correct, what is the actual way of doing it ?

Comment: *Here is what I have tried....I dont't know if any of these are correct*. Well do you get the correct results???

Comment: academic project, I can make it working anyway, doesn't matter... i have to explain each and everything and make everything in the modest way, that's why i'm asking.. and yes I have tried the first query in my question and got exact result, but for some reason, the second one doesn't.. @AlanHay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a query as you would in SQL in the `@Query` and then add another property of the annotation as `nativeQuery = true` and it will run the query as you would in sql.

Pass the parameters in query by adding a `:` in front of them. Also, don't forget to add `@Param` in your auguments.

Something like this:

```
    @Query(value = "select umr from UserMovieRole umr join user u on u.id = umr.userId  where u.userId (#got it by joining tables.) = :userId  and umr.movieID=:movieId", nativeQuery = true)
    returnType yourMethod(@Param("userId") userId, @Param("movieId") movieId);
```

Comment: my query works just fine, and your code has [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsFTJ.png) **All I want to know is what is the most delicate way to do ?**

Comment: I wrote a code structure not an actual code that is why it is showing error

Comment: I can understand, in returnType I have to replace it with my return type, but in userID?? What will I do there, can tell me, please??

Comment: `@Query("select umrj from UserMovieRole.user full join UserMovieRole.movie umrj where umrj.userID=?1 and umrj.movieID=?2")`
The userId in this query you wrote is the same as the userId in my query